# Independence and uncorrelatedness between two normal random vectors.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are normal random vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ and in $\mathbb R^m$, and they are jointly normally distributed i.e. $(X,Y)$ is normally distributed in $\mathbb R^{n+m}$, then are the following equivalent

1. $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=0$;
2. $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Note that it is true when $n=m=1$. Thanks.

Comment: The direction from 2 to 1 follows from the more general fact that independent random variables with finite variances have zero covariance.  That they have a covariance at all is proved using Cauchy-Schwarz.  Probably what is intended in an exercise phrased like this is is a proof of the inference from 1 to 2. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: It is what I think and guess out of my old notes, not an exercise. So I am not claiming my phrasing is correct. Yes, the emphasis is from 1 to 2.

Comment: I suppose to be clear one should mention that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$ is an $n\times m$ matrix $\mathbb E((X-\mathbb E X)(Y-\mathbb E Y)^\top)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes. it is defined that way. @MichaelHardy

Comment: If you have a theorem that says two multivariate normal distributions with the same mean $\mathbb E W$ and the same variance $\operatorname{var}(W) = \mathbb E((W-\mathbb E W)(W-\mathbb E W)^\top)\in\mathbb R^{\ell\times\ell}$ are the same distribution, then you only need to think about $\operatorname{var}\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y\end{bmatrix}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, there is such a theorem, i.e. mean and variance do characterize multivariate normal distribution completely. Why? and how to think about $var([X,Y])$?

Comment: See for instance [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/428188/25632) for 1. implies 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}\newcommand{\cov}{\operatorname{cov}}$
In comments you say you have a theorem that if two multivariate normal distributions have the same mean and the same variance, then they are the same distribution.

You have
$$
\E\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \E X \\ \E Y \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
\begin{align}
\var \begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} & = \E\left( \left(\begin{bmatrix} X \\  Y \end{bmatrix} -\E\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} \right) \left(\begin{bmatrix} X \\  Y \end{bmatrix} -\E\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix} \right)^T \right) \\[10pt]
& = \begin{bmatrix} \var X & \cov(X,Y) \\ \cov(X,Y)^T & \var(Y) \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
The two off-diagonal matrices are $0$, by hypothesis.

Now consider another normal distribution of $(n+m)\times 1$ column vectors: The first $n$ components are distributed exactly as $X$ is distributed and the last $m$ components as $Y$, and they are independent.  That multivariate normal distribution has the same mean (in $\mathbb R^{n+m}$) and the same variance (in $\mathbb R^{(n+m)\times(n+m)}$) as the distribution of $X$ and $Y$.  Now apply the theorem mentioned in the first paragraph above.