# Independence of two random variables derived from a Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

If $X = B_1 + B_3 - B_2$ 
and $Y = B_1 - B_3  + B_2$
Where $B_t$ is Brownian Motion for $t \geq 0$
And I want to state with certainty whether $X$ and $Y$ are indep or not,

do I simply just $\text{Cov}(X,Y) = \text{Cov}(B_1 + B_3 - B_2, B_1 - B_3 + B_2)$ which is non-zero, and thus the two R.v's are not independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that would be a way to do it.

May I suggest the following way of ordering the terms in the covariance calculation?

$$\text{cov}(X,Y) = \text{cov}(B_1+(B_3-B_2),B_1-(B_3-B_2))$$
$$=\text{cov}(B_1,B_1)-\text{cov}(B_1,B_3-B_2)+\text{cov}(B_3-B_2,B_1)-\text{cov}(B_3-B_2,B_3-B_2)$$
$$=\text{var}(B_1)-\text{var}(B_3-B_2)$$
$$=1-1=0.$$

Underway I use that $B_1$ and $B_3-B_2$ are independent, and thus that their covariance is $0$.

You may know that even though the covariance of two random variables is $0$, the random variables may still be dependent. In this case, however, a covariance of $0$ does imply independence (why?)

Comment: Yea I know that independence implies a $0$ covariance, but not vice-versa. But a non-zero covariance implies dependence, obviously.

In this instance, I must have made some mistake in calculations as I got a non-zero covariance. 
I am not sure why here a $0$ Cov implies independence though.

Comment: It is a very special feature of normally distributed variables. If $(X,Y)$ has a normal distribution, then $\text{cov}(X,Y) = 0$ implies that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. See for instance http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006297/independence-and-uncorrelatedness-between-two-normal-random-vectors

Comment: ahh, thanks for that! I had an itch that it would be related to X, Y being normally distributed. I'll read up further into it, however.

You've been a great help, sincerely thank-you